# how to install gnome-keyring and gmime

Tags: gnome, gnome-keyring

i'm trying to install [balsa email reader](http://balsa.gnome.org/download.html) on my ubuntu for dev purposes (i'm new to linux).. and i run into this issue after issuing the `./autogen --enable-all` command:

```
checking wether we have gnome-keyring... no
checking Gmime version.. configure: error: Gmime 2.6 or 2.4 not detected
```

i already ran 
    apt-get install libgmime-2.6-0

and i get `libgmime-2.6-0 is already the newest version` so i'm confused..

**update:** ok it seems that i have gnome-keyring installed.. but then i'm trying to install gmime from [sources](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/gmime/2.6/).. i did the traditional `./configure` and `make`.. but then i run into this issue:

```
error: unknown type name 'gpgme_decrypt_result_t' any ideas?
```

Comment: ah! it seems that keyring is installed.. but what about gmime? i'm trying to install it from sources.. isn't there a simple binary i can just double click and install? or some sudo-apt command for it?

Comment: btw am i asking this question in the right forum? or is it supposed to be in stackoverflow or something?

Comment: You could try asking in [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu) as well both Launchpad and this forum are here for users to help other users.  The difference is while this forum tries to create a single set of questions and answers.  Launchpad has more people asking similar questions: here if a question is too similar to an existing one it gets flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: if you enable the [universe repository](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) there is a package gmime-bin.  If this is what you want it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install -y gmime-bin`

Comment: @WarrenHill, the `-y` is completely unnecessary, it only keeps apt-get from asking questions, which is a bad thing™ when using sudo.

Answer (score 1):

The balsa email client can be installed directly in Ubuntu.

First [Enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) then enter the folowing

```
sudo apt-get install balsa
```

In  Precise (12.04) the version is 2.4.11-1
and in Quantal (12.10) it's 2.4.12-1

Comment: I was actually looking to compile it from source.. b/c the whole point was to debug it.. not to use it as a consumer

Comment: In that case try sudo apt-get build-dep balsa It should install all the build dependences of balsa for you. If you want the source code for the version of balsa in Ubuntu you can use apt-get source balsa but I am assuming you already have the source for a later version. To install the run time dependences take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74478/how-to-install-only-the-dependencies-of-a-package) The code is `sudo apt-get install $(apt-cache depends balsa | grep Depends | sed "s/.*ends:\ //" | tr '\n' ' ') `