# What does the pipe | indicate in apt-cache rdepends?

Tags: apt, apt-cache

As I understand it, `rdepends` lists packages which depend on the specified package.

Example:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends abiword
abiword
Reverse Depends:
  abiword:i386
  xubuntu-desktop
 |python-carquinyol-0.96
  pkpgcounter
  lubuntu-desktop
  junior-writing
  gnome
 |freemind-doc
  abiword-plugin-mathview
  abiword-plugin-grammar
  abiword-dbg
```

In this output, what does `|` mean?

As per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25361/in-apt-cache-depends-output-what-is-the-meaning-of-suggests-recommends), it means 'or' in `apt-cache depends`, however that doesn't seem relevant here (`package1` *or* `package2` depending on `abiword` is impossible).

Comment: I had been assuming it meant the package was already installed. It does not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the example you give, the pipe `|` means that, for python-carquinyol-0.96 or freemind-doc, abiword is not the only package that satisfies the dependencies.

For example, if you installed freemind-doc, abiword *or something else* will do. Running `apt-cache show freemind-doc` you can see:

```
Recommends: evince | openoffice.org-writer | abiword | kword | pdf-viewer
```

which means that installing any of these packages is sufficient.

Compare that to the package xubuntu-desktop, shown without a `|`:

```
Recommends: abiword, abiword-plugin-grammar, ...
```

Here there are no alternatives to abiword; if you want all the recommended packages installed, you must install abiword.

Comment: Better answer than mine so +1 :)