# Do I really need Apache2?

Tags: boot, apache2, startup, systemd, 18.10

I have **apache2.service** enlisted in the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`, taking more than **5.5 seconds**!

Why is **apache2** even installed on my system when I am not running a web server?

**Response to Tomasz Gandor**

Thanks, Tomasz. Here is the output response:

```
$ aptitude why apache2
i   phpliteadmin-themes Depends    phpliteadmin                 
i A phpliteadmin        Recommends apache2 (>= 2.4.6-4~) | httpd
```

And I think it's just a theme, so it would be safe to remove it. Should I?

**Response to PerlDuck**

Thanks, PerlDuck. Here is the output response:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed apache2
apache2
Reverse Depends:
  libapache2-mod-php7.2
 |phpliteadmin
 |javascript-common
  libapache2-mod-php7.2
```

Now, I am not very much certain about what to do!

Also, there is one thing to be noted in the response of `apt-cache rdepends`, and that is the **|** sign before `phpliteadmin` and `javascript-common`. What does this indicate?

And why is `libapache2-mod-php7.2` listed twice in the output, once at the top and once at the bottom of the list?

Comment: Somebody or something must have installed it. It's not there by default.

Comment: It seems apache2 is installed as a dependency of phpliteadmin. Uninstalling Apache2 might break it.

Comment: Yes of course. By "remove it", I meant removing the theme, since I am not using that theme anywhere. And then finally removing apache2.

Comment: The pipe symbol is explained in [What does the pipe | indicate in apt-cache rdepends?](https://askubuntu.com/q/406806/504066). Basically it means _"phpliteadmin depends on apache2 **or some other package (webserver)**"_. When running `apt show phpliteadmin` then we see it recomends either `apache2` or `httpd` and that is what the pipe symbol expresses: `phpliteadmin` needs either apache2 or some other httpd.

Comment: If you want to be really sure, dig further and find out why you need `phpliteadmin`: `aptitude why phpliteadmin`. If you don't, remove that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have aptitude run:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

then:

```
aptitude why apache2
```

This will list packages. If you find any packages preceded by "`i`" and not "`i A`", that's why you have apache2.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up to @TomaszGandor's  [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1127465/504066): in case `aptitude` is not istalled but `apt-cache` is (which I think is by default),
another possibility is:

```
apt-cache rdepends --installed apache2
```

This will list all installed packages that depend on `apache2`.